# Android EditText Hint

Tags: android

I have set a hint for an `EditText`, currently the hint visibility is gone. When a user starts typing, I want to remove the hint text, when the cursor is visible in the `EditText`, not at the time when a user starts to type. How can I do that?

```
<EditText 
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/edittextbg"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
android:gravity="left"
android:id="@+id/Photo_Comments" 
android:layout_width="150dip" 
android:maxLines="1"
android:hint="Write Caption"
android:maxLength="50"
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxWidth="100dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't know whether a direct way of doing this is available or not, but you surely there is  a workaround via code: listen for onFocus event of `EditText`, and as soon it gains focus, set the hint to be nothing with something like `editText.setHint("")`:

This may not be exactly what you have to do, but it may be something like this-

```
myEditText.setOnFocusListener(new OnFocusListener(){
  public void onFocus(){
    myEditText.setHint("");
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't necessary as the default behavior of the Hint on the EditText will disappear when it has focus and not empty.

Comment: This is not the best approach, you can just use a selector applied to the textColorHint. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 61):

You can use the concept of selector. onFocus removes the hint.

```
android:hint="Email"
```

So when `TextView` has focus, or has user input (i.e. not empty) the hint will not display.

Comment: This looks much appropriate option than mine!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is incorrect.  <selector> elements can only be used for drawables and colors; not strings.

Comment: BUT has to be set from xml or resource id

Comment: Can you possibly expand on this, I can't find the proper documentation for the selector tag and how to do this

Answer (score 22):

To complete Sunit's answer, you can use a selector, not to the text string but to the textColorHint. 
You must add this attribute on your editText:

```
android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint_selector"
```

And your text_hint_selector should be:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:color="@color/hint_color" />
</selector>
```

Comment: why is it @color/xxx and not @drawable/xxx?

Comment: @behelit textColorHint receives a color, not a drawable, so the selector must be in the color folder, not the drawable.

Answer (score 2):

```
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            et.setHint(temp +" Characters");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hint. a good answer is more than just a dump of code. You should at least provide some bit of explanation if you intend to be A) helpful to others B) gain reputation for your answer