# Updating Android EditText's hint on focus change using XML only

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I read with interest user [sunit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361288/sunit)'s answer to [this question about updating an EditText's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373888/android-edittext-hint) but have been unable to find any documentation on using the method that I presume he appears to describe there: using the `<selector>` element in an XML layout to dynamically adjust attributes of an `EditText` at runtime when the element is focused/unfocused.

In my case I am actually more interested in adjusting the `android:inputType` element (because the hint disappears for me when the inputType is specified) but adjusting the hint would work just as well.

To be clear I know how to make this change in Java code--I'm trying to find out if there is a way to specify the behavior in XML.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it isn't yet possible.  `<selector>` is only valid to be applied in making state lists out of Drawable and Color resources, it does not yet work for Strings.

With regards to your mention of adjusting `android:inputType` to make the hint disappear, this is actually a known Android bug that will eventually be fixed in later versions so I wouldn't recommend building your code around this functionality as it will break when they fix it:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13895

Since you mentioned that you already know how to do this in the Java code, I won't point out how to call `setHint()` from within a `OnFocusChangeListener` ;)

Cheers.