# android:hint not disappearing onFocus using EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am on Android 3+ and I am trying to add hints to my edit text widgets. I tried adding the hint to the layout as follows...

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/bar_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/bar_name_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />
```

But when I focus on the Text box it writes over the hint instead of the hint disappearing.

[Hint Issue http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg580/scaled.php?server=580&filename=barhintprob.png&res=crop](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg580/scaled.php?server=580&filename=barhintprob.png&res=crop)

I found documentation on adding a onFocus listener to the EditText, but I would like to avoid doing this programatically. The post below also mentioned using selectors but I can't find documentation on how to do that.

[Android EditText Hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373888/android-edittext-hint)

So what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, I had the activity and fragment layout set twice. On Activity onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.edit_consumption);
```

and on the fragment onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_consumption, null);
```

So I had 2 layers of layout. I only had to remove that layout from the Activity onCreate to fix the problem. Maybe you have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by pragmatically

```
EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bar_name); 
name.setHint = "user name"
```

And delete text hint in your XML