# Hint not working in EditText on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, hint

I am using Editbox in which I have used hints. but when I run application, hints do not show. I have tried setting hints programmatically too, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobile_registration_txtDomain"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:hint="@string/hint_domain"
                android:lines="1"
                android:background="@drawable/edittxt_drwable"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#808080" />
```

here is edittxt_drwable.xml code---- which is stored in drawables, used to change color of edittext when focussed and lost focus.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/new_border" />

    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/new_border" />

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/focussed_border" />

    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/focussed_border" />

    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/new_border" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/new_border" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/new_border" />

</selector>
```

here new_border.xml code which gives black border to edittext when it is unclicked.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:thickness="0dp"
         android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="2dp"
           android:color="#808080"/> 

    <corners android:radius="5dp"    
         />

    <padding android:left="10dp"
           android:top="5dp"   
           android:right="10dp"
           android:bottom="5dp"/>

    </shape>
```

here focussed_border.xml code-- which gives orange border to edittxt when edittext is focussed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:thickness="0dp" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke android:width="2dp"
       android:color="#FF8C00"/> 

<corners android:radius="5dp"    
     />

<padding android:left="10dp"
       android:top="5dp"   
       android:right="10dp"
       android:bottom="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: use this URL:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373888/android-edittext-hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,
Add `textColorHint` attribute for your `EditText`

```
android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
```

Comment: thanks.. i set the color.. and it works.. but #FFFFFF (suggested by you) is white color.. so it too doesnt show.. i used blue color and now it is showing.. thanks.. :)

Comment: it needs 15 reputation.. so i cant. :(

Comment: If you wanna to set programmatic use this code snippet edit_text.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem in your string.xml. Did you define hint_domain properly in strings.xml. Can you please show your strings.xml file?

Comment: string file is correct.. problem is resolved now.. thanks for the concern :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
android:inputType="text"
```

with
     android:singleLine="true"

or do

```
android:gravity="right" or android:gravity="left"
```

once using `android:ellipsize="end"` fixed it for me Weird bug.

You can use

```
android:ellipsize="end"

android:maxLines="1"
```

to show your hint text in single line but you wont be able to see the whole text because `android:ellipsize="end"` truncates the text at the end.

Comment: it(hint text) was taking white color by default. i set the color and it works.. thanks for the concern. :)