# EditText hint property not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

When I am using a data binding library within a tab layout the EditText hint does not hide after typing.

```
<layout> <Edittext hint='enter your text'/> <layout>
```

Comment: Share your layout code

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: @chavantr   have you been able to solve your problem based on the answer below?

Comment: No, I have solved problem using another way, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/reg_edu_edittext"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:inputType="textPersonName"
  android:hint=" Educational Qualification"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:hint="Caption..."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but not working for me, I already tried this solution

Comment: @chavantr  please post your xml layout and i will help you

Answer (score -1):

Try following code:

```
<layout>
<data>
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.project.User" />
</data>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:text="@{user.userName}"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="phone number" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion tried all things but not working

Comment: Can you post your XML file? So that will help use to find the exact problem.

Comment: @chavantr if it resolve your problem please add right mark on answer. :)

Comment: not from your suggestion it is different solution thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

May this link will help you to add hint in Edittext and also u will get code to remove it when user enter something in it with EditText hint color style.
Check it..

[Android EditText Hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373888/android-edittext-hint)